# Logging Error Reporting for Multiple Platforms and Multiple Layers

Tags: android, ios, monitoring, logs

I'm fed up.

I am responsible for an AngularJS-based SPA web client and API server back-end written in Symfony. Our SPA runs in browser and on Cordova on Android and iOS. Our back-end runs in AWS.

I'm fed up because I have tried pretty much every common logging tool out there.  I have tried, in no particular order:  New Relic, Fabric, sentry, OpBeat, Ruxit, Soasta.  We also use Google Analytics and Mixpanel for user behavior tracking.

I'm fed up because none of these tools does what I really need, which is to show everything in one place-- everything from the load on individual EC2 instances to how many users are currently logged in to the mobile apps, to whether or not a JS error was thrown inside the Cordova-based mobile apps.

I am looking for a recommendation of which of these tools, or some I have never heard of,  can unite everything in one place.  Of all of these, I feel like New Relic has the best chance of meeting the goal but I don't think I can get our Board of Directors to approve such a large spend if we were to go completely in on New Relic.  Is there something else out there that is either free or at least cheap that can do everything?

I am sick and tired of having to load multiple dashboards and having a pain in the ass time of trying to correlate everything. Right now the thing that's driving me nuts is that sentry isn't reporting JS errors in Cordova.
There are too many of these tools and I want one to rule them all.  Which one?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you want but check out [NagiOS](https://www.nagios.org/)

Nagios Core is completely free and it supports multi-system monitoring, reporting, manitenance and alerts. I've been using it for about 3 months now and didn't experience any problem with it. It's pretty light-weight, fast and reliable.

I believe Nagios XI includes everything you possibly want, but it costs quite a bit as it's now $1995.

Comment: Thanks for your update, Mustafa! As OP especially asked about Android and iOS, maybe you also want to include some words on that? For Android, there are a few [Nagios clients](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_servermon#group_718) available, for iOS I don't know. Also: Do you know whether the free Nagios Core would cover at least the basics needed by the OP?